# CMake and Visual Studio - Specify solution file directory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I've defined a `CMakeLists.txt` file for my project which works correctly.

I use the CMake GUI for generating a Visual Studio Project, and I ask to build the binaries (CMAke cache and other stuff) in the folder `Build` which is in the same folder where `CMakeLists.txt` is.

I was able to specify where the executable and the libraries have to be created.
Is there a way to specify also where the Visual Studio Solution file has to be created? I would like to have it in the root directory, but at the same time I don't want to have also all the other files that CMake creates in the Build directory.

CMake creates the Project I defined in `CMakeLists.txt` but also two other projects: `ALL_BUILD` and `ZERO_CHECK`. What's their utility?
I was able to avoid the creation of `ZERO_CHECK` by using the command `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS On)`.
Is there a way for avoiding also the creation of `ALL_BUILD`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you only switched to CMake very recently, as exactly those questions also popped into my head when I first started using CMake. Let's address them in the order you posted them:

> I use the CMake GUI for generating a Visual Studio Project, and I ask
> to build the binaries (CMAke cache and other stuff) in the folder
> Build which is in the same folder where CMakeLists.txt is.

Don't. Always do an [out-of-source build](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#what-is-an-out-of-source-build) with CMake. I know, it feels weird when you do it the first time, but trust me: Once you get used to it, you'll never want to go back.

Besides the fact that using source control becomes so much more convenient when code and build files are properly separated, this also allows to build separate distinct build configurations from the same source tree at the same time.

> Is there a way to specify also where the Visual Studio Solution file has to be created?

You really shouldn't care.

I see why you do feel that you need full control over how the solution and project files get created, but you really don't. Simply specify the target for the solution as the origin of your out-of-source build and forget about all the other files that are generated. You don't need to worry, and you don't want to worry - this is exactly the kind of stuff that CMake is supposed to take care of *for you*.

Ask yourself: What would you gain if you could handpick the location of every project file? Nothing, because chances are, you will never touch them anyways. CMake is your sole master now...

> CMake creates the Project I defined in CMakeLists.txt but also two
> other projects: ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK. What's their utility? I was
> able to avoid the creation of ZERO_CHECK by using the command
> set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS On). Is there a way for
> avoiding also the creation of ALL_BUILD?

Again, you really shouldn't care. CMake defines a couple of dummy projects which are very useful for certain internal voodoo that you don't want to worry about. They look weird at first, but you'll get used to their sight faster than you think. Just don't try to throw them out, as it won't work properly.
If their sight really annoys you that much, consider [moving them to a folder inside the solution](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/FOLDER.html) so that you don't have to look at them all the time.

Bottom line: CMake feels different than a handcrafted VS solution in a couple of ways. This takes some getting used to, but is ultimately a much less painful experience than one might fear.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I got most of your points and I have to agree with them. The idea of the out-of-source build is powerful. The only reason for which I would like to have the solution file in a different folder, with respect to the project files (which are 3 for each of the types *.vcxproj and *.vcxproj.filter) is that at the end of the day you have to open the solution for working with it. And it would be nicer to have this file separated from the project files and the CMake stuff...but probably a soft link can solve this issue.

Comment: +1, just want to add that keeping solution file in temporary folder will remind you one more time that generation `cmake` -> `*.sln` is one way process, and all `*.sln` modifications will be lost after regeneration

Comment: While out-of-source builds are nice and have their applications, in-source builds can also be convenient. Regarding the comment that version control with out-of-source builds is easier I'd like to disagree. You can always add your in-source build directory to `.gitingore` and thus avoid accidentally adding something that is in there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always have a choice about what your environment requires. Visual Studio's GitHub integration requires that the solution file exists in source control and is at the root of the source tree. It's a documented limitation.

The best I was able to come up with is adding this bit to CMakeList.txt:

```
# The solution file isn't generated until after this script finishes, 
# which means that:
#   - it might not exist (if this is the first run)
#   - you need to run cmake twice to ensure any new solution was copied
set(sln_binpath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.sln)
if(EXISTS ${sln_binpath})
    # Load solution file from bin-dir and change the relative references to 
    # project files so that the in memory copy is as if it had been built in 
    # the source dir.
    file(RELATIVE_PATH prefix 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
    file(READ ${sln_binpath} sln_content)
    string(REGEX REPLACE 
        "\"([^\"]+).vcxproj\""
        "\"${prefix}/\\1.vcxproj\"" 
        sln_content
        "${sln_content}")

    # Compare the updated contents with the existing source path sln, if it
    # exists and is the same we don't want to disturb VS by touching it.
    set(sln_srcpath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.sln)
    set(old_content "")
    if(EXISTS ${sln_srcpath})
        file(READ ${sln_srcpath} old_content)
    endif()
    if(NOT old_content STREQUAL sln_content)
        file(WRITE ${sln_srcpath} ${sln_content})
    endif()
endif()
```

What would be helpful is if cmake had a way to run post generation scripts, but I couldn't find one.

Other ideas that didn't work out:

1. wrap cmake inside a script that does the same thing, but:

   - telling users to run a seperate script isn't simpler than saying to run cmake twice. Especially since needing to run cmake twice isn't a foreign concept.
2. put it in a pre-build step, but

   - building is common and changing the build is rare
   - changing the solution from builds inside the IDE makes it do... things
3. use add_subdirectory because that's suppose to finish first

   - it appeared to make the vcxproj's immediately, but not the sln until later, but I didn't try as hard because this adds a bunch of additional clutter I didn't want - so maybe this can be made to work

Comment: This bit of code is awesome and does exactly what I needed, thanks!